# redirecting to edit action onclick of a radio button doesnt work

Tags: forms, rails-3.1

```
<% @divisions.each do |division| %>
  <td class="user_radio"><%= radio_button_tag("division_ids[]", division.id, false, :onClick=> 'redirect_to edit_division_path(division)')%></td>
  /* rest of the elements in the division */
  <% end %>
```

I need that on clicking the radio button the page gets redirected to the edit_division_path for the division being clicked.

But nothing happens. No error or anything else..

What am I doing wrong?

I am using rails 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` is a javascript thing.

What you want is something like this:

```
:onClick => 'location.href="' + edit_division_path(division) + '"'
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much... I needed just this... :D

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick = "document.location.href='somepage.htm'"
```